# Objective array giving Undefined property stdClass?

Tags: php, php-5.3, json

simply i have JSON array which converted to objective array to working with it .
each time i tried to echo any property (Object) from the array it gives error

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$title
```

this is the array

```
stdClass Object
(
    [info] => stdClass Object
        (
            [title] => Categories
            [num_of_cate] => 5
            [color] => grey
        )

)
```

Original JSON Array

```
{"info":{"title":"Categories","num_of_cate":5,"color":"grey"}}
```

and this how i tried to echo the property

```
echo $info->title
```

Comment: Don't you mean `$object->info->title`, where `$object` is what you gave to `print_r()`?

Comment: bit of a long shot however have you double checked the output of the json array in a normal text editor. The key may not actually be title and could have normally invalid characters as part of the name that have not been displayed when using print_r

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton If only comments could be accepted as answers eh? Re-write that as an answer mate, it's correct :)

Comment: what i pasted within the post is the print_r result

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$json = '{"info":{"title":"Categories","num_of_cate":5,"color":"grey"}}';
$decoded = json_decode($json);
echo $decoded->info->title; // Categories
```

At the moment, you're trying to access the equivalent of `$decoded->title`, which doesn't exist - hence the error.